# Count from two different tables with same column name and group tehm if same name

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the same structure:

Table -1:

```
+----------------------+--------------+-----+
| Field                | Type         | Key |
+----------------------+--------------+-----+
| id                   | int(5)       | PRI | 
| country              | varchar(500) |     | 
+----------------------+--------------+-----|
```

Table -2:

```
+----------------------+--------------+-----+
| Field                | Type         | Key |
+----------------------+--------------+-----+
| id                   | int(5)       | PRI | 
| country              | varchar(500) |     | 
+----------------------+--------------+-----|
```

The data in the table will be as following:
Table -1:

```
+----+---------+
|id  | country |
+----+---------+
| 1  | A       | 
| 2  | B       |   
| 3  | A       | 
| 4  | A       | 
| 5  | B       | 
+----+---------+
```

Table -2:

```
+----+---------+
|id  | country |
+----+---------+
| 1  | A       | 
| 2  | B       |   
| 3  | B       | 
| 4  | B       | 
| 5  | B       | 
+----+---------+
```

When i use the following query statement :

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS result FROM table-1 GROUP BY country UNION SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS result FROM table-2 GROUP BY country;
```

I get the result as following:

```
+--------+---------+
|country | result  |
+--------+---------+
| A      | 3       | 
| B      | 2       |   
| A      | 1       | 
| B      | 4       | 
+--------+---------+
```

Which shows the count of table-1 and table-2 seperately. But i want the count to be combined as following:

```
+--------+---------+
|country | result  |
+--------+---------+
| A      | 4       | 
| B      | 6       |   
+--------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.country,count(t.country)
from 
(
select * from table1
union all 
select * from table2
) t group by t.country
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f84a56/2)**

Comment: will this work if the number of columns in the two tables are different ?

Comment: FYI ..During union no. of column should be same.Let me know your condition/case i can give you query with desired output

Comment: If there are 3 columns in table-1 and 4 columns in table-2, common among them is the country column where the count is required..Can you please let me know in this case..\

Comment: @user5358888 ..can you give the fiddle link with table structure

Comment: Here in i want the combined count of the country's from two tables

Comment: @user5358888 Here is solution for your trouble http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d47630/9 hav fun :-)

Comment: same as above logic....learn from the last one fiddle that i have done ...and do yourself ..That will improve your skill of code rather than copy paste